# How Do I List a Buildpack on Heroku Elements Marketplace

Tags: heroku

It's nice that the Heroku Elements Marketplace exists, but I haven't been able to find out how to list/publish/add a custom Heroku Buildpack to it.

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks

Does anybody know how this might be accomplished?  Does anybody know of official Heroku documentation regarding how to do so, or is it a complete mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That list is simply buildpacks with recent deploys (when the selector is set to "Popularity"). It shows the "recent deploys" numbers for each and sorts in descending order. You can also sort by name, etc.

There is no special way to add your buildpack to this list: just deploy apps with your buildpack. Heroku's Buildpacks are open source and they [allow third-party buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks). So there's no special gate-keeping.

Source: I asked someone who works at Heroku.